# queueMicrotask или Promise и async await

Tags: javascript

не давно встретил метод queueMicrotask и как я понял это аналог Promise и async await или я не так понял и можно ли его спокойно использовать

Comment: вроде похоже на то

Comment: где встретил? в каком виде?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`queueMicrotask` не является "аналогом" [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) или, тем более [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)/[`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).

Зависимость тут обратная: [`Promise` планируют свои коллбэки с помощью `queueMicrotask`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide)

То есть `queueMicrotask` – это аналог `setTimeout`. Разница заключается в том, что `setTimeout` добавляет в очередь [таск](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#Tasks), в том время как `queueMicrotask` добавляет [`микротаск`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#Microtasks).

Подробнее про таски и микротаски можно [смотреть в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide)

```js
let callback = () => console.log("Regular timeout callback has run");

let urgentCallback = () => console.log("*** Oh noes! An urgent callback has run!");

console.log("Main program started");
setTimeout(callback, 0);
queueMicrotask(urgentCallback);
console.log("Main program exiting");
```

Судя по [таблице совместимости](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask#Browser_compatibility) данная функция реализована во всех современных браузерах, кроме IE